# What does require() actually return, the file or the function

Tags: javascript, node.js

For example, I have profile.js

```
var EventEmitter = require("events").EventEmitter;
var https = require("https");
var http = require("http");
var util = require("util");

    function Profile(username) {
     // function code here
    }

    util.inherits( Profile, EventEmitter );

    module.exports = Profile;
```

In my app.js, I have

```
var Profile = require("./profile.js");


var studentProfile = new Profile("chalkers");

/**
* When the JSON body is fully recieved the 
* the "end" event is triggered and the full body
* is given to the handler or callback
**/
studentProfile.on("end", console.dir);

/**
* If a parsing, network or HTTP error occurs an
* error object is passed in to the handler or callback
**/
studentProfile.on("error", console.error);
```

So the variable is the profile.js itself or the function Profile(username)? What if the profile.js have different functions, say I have function SetProfile(username) in the profile.js, how should I export those two functions and use them in the app.js?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `require(...)` function returns the `module.exports` value from the "required" module, and in the case its the `Profile` function.

---

As an aside, I have no idea what "*return the file*" or "*the Profile is the profile.js itself*" means.

Comment: What if the profile.js have different functions, say I have function SetProfile(username) in the profile.js, how should I export those two functions and use them in the app.js?

Comment: `module.exports.x = function x() {}; module.exports.y = function y() {};`

Comment: Can I import them in one place in the app.js? Like var Functions = require('./profile.js'), and then use Functions.x() , Function.y()

Comment: Exactly that. Try it out and see