# what is return type of require('express')?

Tags: javascript, express, require

could you please tell me what is return type of require('express') ?

I search in google find the solution
[What does require() actually return, the file or the function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40270731/what-does-require-actually-return-the-file-or-the-function)

but still i am confuse

**why it behave both object and button**

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var router = express.Router();

example there is is file express.js

module.exports = function(){

console.log('====')
}
```

so it return function  ? how I will use as object ?

is Router is added in prototye of express

Comment: Possible copy of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27599614/var-express-requireexpress-var-app-express-what-is-express-is-it

Comment: A function is an Object (`(function() {}) instanceof Object` is true)

Answer (score 1):

From looking at the source code of express js [here](https://github.com/expressjs/express/blob/master/lib/express.js) , it exports createApplication() which in turn returns a function. so I believe,the return type of express is a function.

In general, the return type of a require call depends on what the required file exports from its source code using module.exports